# How to test for in class body method calls?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

  acts_as_tree

end
```

How to test that acts_as_tree gets called?
Or that any other in class body method gets called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to test that it gets called? Of course it gets called!

What you really should be doing is testing that your application behaves the way you want it to behave. You write test cases illustrating how you want your application to behave, and then you run the test cases to check that the application does indeed behave that way.

You can write test cases checking that `Category` instances have parents and children, that you can retrieve the list of children given a parent, that you can create a new `Category` instance and add it to some pre-existing `Category` instance's list of children, or various other behaviors important to your application.

Comment: Well, you got a good point there. But somehow it still feels more natural for me to test that acts_as_tree method is called inside class rather than test for methods it implements. It's like RSpec testing that a module is included rather than testing for newly included methods...

Comment: This is a simple example, but there are cases where it might not be feasible (or possible) to run the entire application and do integration tests. Some people *do* think that unit testing is a good idea. Or, (how I came to this page) maybe your class is a plugin for something and *can't* run completely on its own.

Comment: Sure. For example maybe you have a module with an include hook. But that's a completely different scenario from the question asked above.